# Dell 2-in-1 keyboard/trackpad bug

Tags: keyboard, suspend, touchpad, dell, disconnect

Did some searching but couldn't find the exact issue.

Sometimes, not always, when I open it up from sleep, the keyboard and trackpad do not register any input. The touchscreen does, as I can swipe up to the password box input, but not actually input anything.

There is a fix: physically flipping the laptop to tablet mode and back. Then everything works. What can I do to fix this so I don't have to keep physically fixing the problem?

Dell Inspiron 13 (i3-7100U/4GB/1TB) Product sku: QF9-01403